# How to run a custom WAR file using tomcat server from within IntelliJ Idea Ultimate?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I have configured IntelliJ Idea 2022.1.4 Ultimate with Tomcat 10.0.23 as one of the application server. It runs OK !!!

I have a WAR file for which i don't have source. How can configure a project in IntelliJ to run the WAR file i have with Tomcat?
i.e Where to put the WAR files so that I have a do-nothing project in IntelliJ which just uses my WAR? Makes sense?

Can i just drop the WAR under WebApps folder of tomcat install?

Or is there a better way to specify path to external WAR via IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: This tutorial https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html might help.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov : This tutorial tells how to create a WAR from sources and then deploy. My question was more about using a pre-built WAR